# Проблема с тегом include и наследованием в шаблоне Django

Tags: python, django, шаблоны

Есть шаблон base.html:

```
<head>
{% include 'head.html' %}
</head>
```

Во включенном файле head.html есть блок:

```
{% block title %}{% endblock %}
```

В приложении я создаю шаблон, который унаследуется от base.html, в котором хочу вывести переменную в блоке title:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}
  {{title}}
{% endblock %}
```

Но такая схема не работает - выдает ошибку. Что не так?
Если я правильно понимаю, тег include должен включать шаблон в шаблон как его часть, без ограничений.

Comment: Вы забыли приложить текст ошибки :)

Comment: @tutankhamun
Так никакой ошибки не выдает. Просто выводит текст 'default title', что стоит в блоке {% block title %} default title {% endblock %} в файле head.html. Если прописую значение в base.html, то его как бы вообще нету

Answer (score 1):

Плохая новость для вас. Вот что написано по этому поводу в [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#include):

> Blocks are evaluated before they are included. This means that a template that includes blocks from another will contain blocks that have already been evaluated and rendered - not blocks that can be overridden by, for example, an extending template.

То есть переопределение содержимого блоков при наследовании шаблона не происходит. Поэтому вы получаете результат о котором написали в комментарии.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Весьма странное поведение, если честно. Логично предположить, что тег include как раз служит для того, чтобы разбить один шаблон на составляющие блоки. Теперь придется выкручиваться лишь наследованием (тегом extends) для того, чтобы разбить шаблон на более простые составляющие части

Comment: Мне тоже кажется нелогичным. Я не работал с Django, но работал с Twig в php и искренне считал, что это по сути один шаблонизатор. Оказалось просто похож. Фнукционал Twig основан на Jinja для python. Возможно стОит подключить к Django его. Или например в блоки во вложенных шаблонах просто вставлять переменные без переопределения блока. Это должно работать (контекст-то один)